# Magento 2 : Display Custom Product Attribute If it has a Value

Tags: magento2, product, php, attributes

I have created a custom product attribute and added the code below to display them within the grouped product table.

```
<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Breaking Strain')) ?>" class="col item">
        <?= $my_attr = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($_item->getId(),'breakingstrain',$_item->getId()); ?>
</td>
```

(/public_html/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml)

However not every product will use this custom attribute, so I don't want the td to be visible if there is no data set within the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code.

```
<?php $my_attr = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($_item->getId(),'breakingstrain',$_item->getId()); ?>
<?php if($my_attr != '') : ?>
<td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Breaking Strain')) ?>" class="col item">
      <?php echo $my_attr ?>  
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This works but gets the ID of the attribute, is there a way to get the value of the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<?php if($my_attr = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($_item->getId(),'breakingstrain',$_item->getId())): ?>
<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Breaking Strain')) ?>" class="col item">
    <?= $my_attr; ?>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```